# How do I tell if the current action is in an Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

Within my `application.html.erb`, I want to be able to detect if the currently rendering page is from within a mounted engine (Forem, if that matters), so that I can add an `active` class to the nav bar. Is there an easy way to detect this?

I'm using Rails 3.2.

Comment: `request[:controller].include? 'forem'` shouldn't be enough?

Comment: That's a hack that might work, but it seems crazy to me that there isn't a definitive, non-hacky answer.

Comment: I've accidentally deleted my last comment, so I'll write it again. It that seems too hacky maybe just add `before_filter` by `class_eval` to `Forem::ApplicationController` with some method setting instance method like `@forem` so all controllers inheriting from it will have it and then you can use it in your view like `<%= add_active if @forem %>`?

Comment: What I mean is that it seems strange that the only way to find out if the current rendering page is by parsing the controller name out of the request. I'd assumed there would be something indicating the engine that was rendering the page, but I guess not! :-)

Comment: Actually, if going that way the simplest way of obtaining current controller is just `controller`, I can't find any way of getting its origin easier than parsing its name, maybe someone will share better approach. However, I've already seen similar code in few apps so maybe there's no better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a helper method in `Forem::ApplicationController` by reopening the class:

```
Forem::ApplicationController.class_eval do
  def forem?
    true
  end

  helper_method :forem?
end
```

Add the above file in `app/decorators/forem/application_controller_decorator.rb` for example.

This way every time a view is rendered by Forem's controller you would be able to call `forem?` within your view.

**application.html.erb**

```
<% if forem? %>
  # do something
<% end %>
```

You might want to check if the current instance `respond_to?(:forem?)` first, or add a `forem?` method returning `false` in your own `application_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

A very similar approach can be done without the use of decorator loading (just using Rails default loading), e.g. for Thredded:

```
#This file would be at app/controllers/thredded/application_controller.rb in your main_app repo

require_dependency File.expand_path("../../app/controllers/thredded/application_controller",
  Thredded::Engine.called_from)

module Thredded
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
    def thredded?
      true
    end
  end
end
```

and then add the default value and helper_method declaration in your own ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :thredded? 
  def thredded?
    false
  end

  # etc

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<% if controller.controller_name == ""something" && 
               controller.action_name == "something" %> 
   Do someting  <!-- add you class -->
<% end %>
```